Think before adding a canned comment in review if there's already a canned comment from review
TL;DR: If there's already a canned comment on the post you're reviewing, just upvote it, don't post another canned comment.
Background
Some review queues, such as Low Quality Posts, have the option to leave a canned comment. These comments let the reviewer easily post an helpful explanation. The new user, instead of having their answer silently deleted, is taught how the site works. Everyone wins.
That's what the canned comments are for: providing helpful explanation. Canned comments are not for proving you know what's wrong with the post. You do not need to select the "correct" canned comment.
The problem
Why do I mention that? Because of situations like this:

If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the Ask Question button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - From Review 12 hours ago
This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question. To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can follow this question. Once you have enough reputation, you can also add a bounty to draw more attention to this question - From Review 8 hours ago
If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the Ask Question button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - From Review 6 hours ago
This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question. To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can follow this question. Once you have enough reputation, you can also add a bounty to draw more attention to this question - From Review 1 hour ago

This isn't welcoming. To the new user, this appears like people piling up, everyone saying at once how their post messed up. They do not need to be told four separate times that new questions should be asked as new questions. They especially don't need duplicated comments.
The solution
Recall the goal of canned comments: brief, information-dense explanation for the new user. Since they only need one explanation, don't post a canned comment if there's already a similar one. Instead, upvote the previous comment (indicating support without piling on inbox notifications) or, if you're feeling up to it, post a more detailed/personalized comment.
We were all new users, once. How would you rather learn the rules of a new place: from one simple explanation, or from four identical ones all piling on? We can all help fix this. Upvote, don't duplicate comments. Please.

This looks a [tag:bug] worth posting on [meta.se]. Choosing a canned comment which is already present used to upvote an existing one, which is fine in my book.

@Glorfindel The exact duplicate comments are from different queues (Late Answers and Low Quality Posts, as I recall). I don't believe the queues ever talked to each other.

Oh, I didn't realize that (and for reviewers, there's no way to tell the difference when they're reviewing). Still, it looks to me like a system problem, not a people problem :)

Could you edit to include the links on those "From Review" words? I don't think it's a problem to "de-anonymise" the question, because you're not accusing anyone of bad behaviour - it's a system problem more than anything else. I wanted to check how many of those comments are coming from the same review item, because I think the behaviour @Glorfindel describes is still current, so maybe the only problem is people choosing different deletion reasons from the options presented in the review queue - and if there are really exact duplicate auto-comments, that's worth posting on [meta.se].

@Randal'Thor as I told Glorfindel, the exact duplicate comments are from different queues. The first two are from one queue, and the last two are from a different queue. The only upvote on any of them came from me clicking the upvote button (instead of selecting a duplicate canned comment).

Comment for copy-pasting when you see this "in the wild": @<username>, instead of re-posting a canned comment, please [upvote](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7610/) the pre-existing one.

I have seen situations like bobble described and I agree it is unwelcome and excessive.
Perhaps one solution would be to change the review system so that after someone has used a canned comment, further canned comments would be disabled.

This isn't something that we can implement on Puzzling, however. Additionally, these comments come from different queues (which don't talk to each other much), and some comments are truly orthogonal (compare an ask-a-new-question comment to a link-only-answer comment). Some relevant main-meta feature requests are here and here.
